# SQL Query Only Want Midnight Samples

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, timestamp

I am running a query on a totalizator and I only want the samples from 00.00.00 hrs. I have searched to see if I can use wildcards on the timestamp field and have come up with no answers. I have commented out the line below where I tried just using '00:00:00' for the "ts" (Timestamp) field in the table because it doesn't work. Is there a way that I can only pull the midnight samples from the table?

```
SELECT TOP (100) percent
       [ts] AS 'Timestamp'
      ,[value]
  FROM [enteliwebDB].[dbo].[UASTP_150000_TL63]
  where ts > dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0 ,getdate())-31, 0)
  --and ts = '00:00:00'

Timestamp                   value
2019-01-21 00:00:00.0040000 1122981.5
2019-01-21 01:00:00.0030000 1125681.625
2019-01-21 02:00:00.0020000 1128380.75
2019-01-21 03:00:00.0020000 1131080.5
2019-01-21 04:00:00.0020000 1133778.625
2019-01-21 05:00:00.0020000 1136477.625
2019-01-21 06:00:00.0030000 1139177.875
2019-01-21 07:00:00.0010000 1141877.375
2019-01-21 08:00:00.0030000 1144579.125
2019-01-21 09:00:00.0010000 1147277.625
2019-01-21 10:00:00.0030000 1149976.375
2019-01-21 11:00:00.0000000 1152676.25
2019-01-21 12:00:00.0020000 1155376.75
2019-01-21 13:00:00.0030000 1158078.25
2019-01-21 14:00:00.0040000 1160776.875
2019-01-21 15:00:00.0030000 1163476.125
2019-01-21 16:00:00.0000000 1166175
2019-01-21 17:00:00.0000000 1168872.75
2019-01-21 18:00:00.0020000 1171571.5
2019-01-21 19:00:00.0030000 1174271.875
2019-01-21 20:00:00.0010000 1176972.625
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you've got milliseconds in there, which you can round off by including only times in the first second after midnight.  I'm using datediff to count how many whole seconds passed since midnight of the day we are in

```
SELECT TOP (100) percent
       [ts] AS 'Timestamp'
      ,[value]
  FROM [enteliwebDB].[dbo].[UASTP_150000_TL63]
  where ts > dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0 ,getdate())-31, 0) and (DATEDIFF(second,cast(ts as date),ts)) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conversion to type `TIME`, and compare that with `00:00:00`:

```
AND CONVERT(TIME, [ts]) = '00:00:00'
```

Or if you want all records regardless if the milliseconds are not always exactly 0 (as in your example):

```
AND CONVERT(TIME, [ts]) >= '00:00:00'
AND CONVERT(TIME, [ts])  < '00:00:01'
```